# Flutter Buttons which updates the body

Tags: flutter, button, setstate

Hello how can I make 2 buttons which will update the body content like tabs. When you click on 1st button it will be shown as selected and the content will change (appBar title, body, slider etc.). When you click to another one It will be shown as selected and will change the content again. But the buttons will appear in both contents. like in this example below

There are look like tabs but the difference is they are changing state and updating the page

[image]

Comment: `setState` in `onPressed` of the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to create a global variable which holds the value of the button selected.

Put it out of the main() method.

You can access it from every class and file in your project.

Other ways would require a Provider and state management architecture.

Working sample:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

int selectedButton = 0;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Page1(),
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Text('Page1'),
          MyWidget(selectedButton),
        ])));
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Text('Page2'),
          MyWidget(selectedButton),
        ])));
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int selected;

  MyWidget(this.selected);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(children: <Widget>[
      RawMaterialButton(
          child: Text("Go to page1"),
          fillColor: selected == 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
          onPressed: () {
            selectedButton = 0;
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page1()));
          }),
      RawMaterialButton(
          child: Text("Go to page2"),
          fillColor: selected == 1 ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
          onPressed: () {
            selectedButton = 1;
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2()));
          })
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: please can you provide an example

Comment: Oh thank you soo much, i have a question how can i access the global variable int selectButton from another file ?

Comment: Every global variable is already visible by other files. Or if you want to be more clear put it as a static variable in a class in a new file and then import that file in all other files.

Comment: thank you again, i understand, just imported the library and used "as" annotation it worked for me.

Comment: Sorry in this example you are redirecting with Navigator.push and changing  page. Is there a way where i can change only body content of the same page without changing to another page by pressing this buttons?

Comment: Sure, do like this: home: yourVariableValue ? Page1() : Page2()